# How do I parse the following AJAX reponse in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am making an AJAX call and I get the following:

```
{"status":"Results Found","errorcode":"0","result":[{"name":"test","id":"1"},{"name":"some","id":"2"}]}
```

What I want to do with the result element is to make a unordered list using javascript. For example:

```
<ul>
<li> test </li>
<li> some </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone assist?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem? To transform JSON into a JS object? Or to iterate over its properties?

Comment: Is the problem that you're having trouble parsing the response? Or that you don't quite know how to put it into an element that you can then display?

Comment: I don't know how to quite put it into an element. I see the functions below and I thought there was an easier JSON to javascript conversion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and this is a good practice too:

```
var q = '{"status":"Results Found","errorcode":"0","result":[{"name":"test","id":"1"},{"name":"some","id":"2"}]}';
var o = $.parseJSON(q);
alert(o.status); // for test, remove it
alert(o.errorcode); // for test, remove it
var ul = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < o.result.length; i++) {
    alert(o.result[i].name + " = " + o.result[i].id); // for test, remove it
    ul += "<li>" + o.result[i].name + "</li>";
}
ul += "</ul>"; // final html, use it
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var html = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < data["result"].length; i++) {
  html += "<li>" + data["result"][i] + "</li>";
}
html += "</ul>";
```

and then you can use the `html` string to dynamically create a list.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
// TODO: global variable 'ajax' should be an XMLHttpRequest instance.
// TODO: change last line 'document.body.appendChild' to append where you need to.
var response = JSON.parse( ajax.responseText );
var results = response.result;
var ul = document.createElemnt('ul');
var li;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = results[ i ].name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

document.body.appendChild(ul);
```